# Elixir serial port connection

Tags: serial-port, elixir

I'm exploring connecting to a serial device with Elixir.  The only library I've found is [this one](https://github.com/bitgamma/elixir_serial).  I'm still trying to wrap my head around Genservers and before I start writing out a program/application I want to just do some simple experimenting in `iex`, but I don't know how to get started.
I've started a new mix project, added the `elixir_serial` package as a dependency and started up iex with `sudo iex -S mix`.  (I'm on ubuntu, and currently if I don't use sudo I get an error about read/write permissions when trying to connect, but that's a separate issue afaik).
I seem to be able to connect ok:

```
iex(3)> {:ok, serial} = Serial.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.124.0>}
iex(4)> Serial.open(serial, "/dev/ttyUSB0")
:ok
iex(5)> Serial.set_speed(serial, 9600) 
:ok
iex(6)> Serial.connect(serial)
:ok
iex(7)> Serial.send_data(serial, <<0x01, 0x02, 0x03>>)
:ok
```

But I don't know how to receive data back.  I've tried putting in the code suggested in the `elixir_serial` README:

```
def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
# do something with the data
end
```

both in iex (wrapped in a defmodule MySerial do end block) and in the mix project main file, just sticking in an `IO.puts(data)` in the function.

I'm obviously missing something here, does the Serial connection need the iex pid to send data back to? I don't understand whether I need to set up a GenServer app to read data, or if I can use the `elixir_serial` api to read data back from the serial port.

As I say I'm wrapping my head around GenServer, I understand the generalities, but I'd like to know how to start using this package to just test sending and receiving data before I start building an application around it.

Comment: Are you trying to write a test to act as if the serial device sent back data?

Comment: I'd like to send a command to the device, and then read the result of that command on the device.  I'm sending data to a Cisco switch, and so need to essentially emulate human interaction on the Cisco cli, so I want to get an idea of the results of different commands.  (in previous experience with pyserial there were certain gotchas that made this tricky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the docs in `elixir_serial` for Serial.start_link:

> Starts a serial port. The process invoking this function will receive
>     messages in the form of `{:elixir_serial, pid, data}`.

So, you don't actually need a `GenServer` to handle the response. Simply add a receive block in the code with this sort of format:

```
receive do
  {:elixir_serial, serial_pid, data} ->
    IO.puts "Received data"
    Serial.send_data(serial_pid, "ACK: Received Message")
end
```

Essentially, the library receives the call from its C counterpart and then sends a message to the process who started the `Serial` link.

> send(pid, {:elixir_serial, self(), data})

See https://github.com/bitgamma/elixir_serial/blob/master/lib/serial.ex#L129

Comment: Thanks Christian.  I was getting distracted by the Genserver, I didn't even think to just use `flush`. Getting somewhere now, much appreciated.